# Prove that the map $ z\mapsto z^3 $ is a closed map.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Prove that the map which winds the plane three times on itself given, in terms of complex numbers, by $ z\mapsto z^3 $ is a closed map.

I was trying to solve problem 20 in chapter 2 from *Basic Topology* by Armstrong.

I have already proved that the map $ z\mapsto z^3 $ is an open map, how am I supposed to show that it is also a closed map?

Can I directly show that $ \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}: z\mapsto z^3 $ is a homeomorphism thus it is also a closed map?

**Edit**: A *closed map* takes closed sets to closed sets. Furthermore, a map is a continuous function.

Comment: It can't be a homeomorphism as usually defined--- not one to one. BTW what definition of "closed map" do you use?

Comment: @coffeemath A closed map takes closed sets to closed sets. Furthermore, a map is a continuous function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$z \to z^{3}$ is not one-to-one so it is not  a homeomorphism. Let $C$ be a closed set and consider  the image $\{z^{3}:z \in C\}$. Suppose $z_n^{3} \to \zeta$. We have to show that $\zeta$ can be written as $z^{3}$ for some $z$. Now $\{z_n^{3}\}$ is a bounded sequence which implies that $\{z_n\}$ is also bounded. There is a subsequence of this sequence converging to some $z$ and continuity of the map $z \to z^{3}$ tells you that $\zeta =z^{3}$.

As requested by the OP I am providing a second proof that does not use compactness. There an  open sector containing $\zeta$  in which $z \to z^{3}$ is a homeomorphism. [In any sector of the type $|\arg(\theta) - \arg(\theta_0)| <\pi /3$ the given map is a homeomorphism].  We can apply the inverse map $ z \to z^{1/3} $ to conclude that $z_n \to \zeta ^{1/3}$ so $\zeta ^{1/3} \in C$.

Comment: Note that $z_n^{3} \to \zeta$ implies $z_{n_k}^{3} \to \zeta$. So if $z_{n_k} \to z$ then $z_{n_k}^{3} \to z^{3}$ and $z_{n_k}^{3} \to \zeta$ which implies $\zeta=z^{3}$.

Comment: Nice! But at this point in the book, we haven't learned compactness. So I am thinking that there should be another way without using the compactness.

Comment: @Philip I have added another proof to my answer.

Comment: Does this local homeomorphism also imply openness of the map?